# slowness in react native application

Tags: android, react-native, use-context, use-reducer

I recently created an application with react native in which I use Axios to request addresses of images from a database, the problem arises that on the main screen I made the request and through a map, I render a list of images and when moving to another screen 2 I make another request Axios to get other information and render another list of images the problem arises that this second screen slows down, I see that if I make requests two requests on a screen it slows too much, there is some way to improve, even if I place an image with URI same lens as the following screen, this problem can be solved.

Comment: Create a sandbox for the users to test. You could create and share it [here](https://snack.expo.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Good, for which the answer is useful, looking for information and consulted for the rendering of images with map. and image address {uri:} it is good to store images in amazon s3 bucket, in my case it sends addresses of my images stored on my server, but the problem is that they had a very high weight, which varied from 1 Mb to 2Mb I compressed the images up to 200 Kb and 150 Kb and there are no problems.